# double click needed to activate binded mousedown/up

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is part of my code:

```
$('.toggle_box').each(function (){ 
    var timeout, longtouch;  
    $(this).bind('mousedown', function() {
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            longtouch = true;
        }, 1000);

    $(this).bind('mouseup', function(){
        if (!longtouch) {
            clearTimeout(timeout)
            var state = $(this).find('.switch').attr('data-state');
            if(state == "off"){
                $(this).find('.switch').attr('data-state','on');
            }
            else{
                $(this).find('.switch').attr('data-state','off');
            }
            var choice = $(this).parent();
            ckbmovestate(choice)
        }
        else{
            alert("3")
        };
    });
})
});
```

when I click an element (mousedown and up) it works fine, but the 2e time I have to double click the element for it to fire. It looks like the second click resets the bind so that the 3e can use it again. just weird.

Here is a demo: Not valid anymore...
It is the orange checkbox :) (please check in safari/chrome)

thank you for your help :)

Comment: do I need to unbind and rebind or something?

Comment: You shouldn't need to un/rebind. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve with the `longtouch` variable? In the code you've supplied you don't initialise it when you declare it and once it is true you don't ever set it back to false. And in the else branch of your mouseup function you're trying to clear a timeout that would've already been executed.

Comment: here added a line :). The longtouch is needed to differentiate long clicks and short ones :)

Comment: why does .live() not work here? :s

Comment: I figured you were doing something with short and long clicks, but still you don't ever set longtouch back to false. Are there still some missing lines in between the mousedown and mouseup code? At the moment your bind('mouseup') is actually *inside* your bind('mousedown') function, so it will run the bind operation every time you click the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the code posted here ... http://jsfiddle.net/qv4Ve/2/

You were binding the mouseup event inside the mousedown event handler. You ought to have to bound them independently of each other.

```
$(this).bind('mousedown', function() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {longtouch = true;}, 1000);
    console.log("inside mouse down");
});

$(this).bind('mouseup', function(){
    console.log("inside mouse up");
    if (longtouch === false) {
        clearTimeout(timeout)
        var state = $(this).find('.switch').attr('data-state');
        if(state == "off"){
            $(this).find('.switch').attr('data-state','on');
        }
        else {
            $(this).find('.switch').attr('data-state','off')
        ;}

        var choice = $(this).parent();
        ckbmovestate(choice)
    }
    else {
        alert("is a long touch")
    };
});
```

The code in the fiddle posted above works the way you want it to ...